# Como distribuir as entidades entre projetos?

Tags: java, rest, microsserviços

Tenho dúvidas se existem boas praticas para distribuição de entidades entre projetos. Digamos que tenho um microservice REST em java, que disponibilize um cliente(id, nome, endereço) através do GET e outro microserviço que precise consumir este primeiro microservice.

Como poderia evitar a duplicação de código entre esses dois projetos? Colocando a entidade cliente em um JAR separado e fazer os dois microservicos usarem este JAR como dependência? Tem outra forma de minimizar a duplicação de código entre esses microservicos em java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com certeza isso pode ser uma grande questão em se tratando de sistemas distribuídos como microserviços, você pode distribuir as classes em comum em um **JAR** separado e utilizar nos projetos, mas para que isso realmente funcione a cobertura de Testes e o correto versionamento das dependências é fundamental, porque imagine uma possível alteração nesta **lib**, isto poderia impactar diretamente em seus projetos.

Mas um outro ponto importante, esta estratégia de **libs** funciona quando você tem poucos MS na arquitetura, quando a quantidade aumenta fica muito complicado controlar estas dependências, então a saída é a criação dos códigos específicos para cada MS.